# MySQL to append all the column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `material_line_item` and in that table 3 columns are there `1.item_master_id` `2.received_quantity` and `3.ordered_quantity` I want a Query to calculate all the quantities in both the fields (`` received_quantity` and `ordered_quantity ``) based upon the `item_master_id`.

[image: **Screen Snap for this**]

Comment: Show us the expected result (with that table data.)

Comment: I already added one snap for this.

Comment: I can't find any received_quantity and ordered_quantity values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help:

```
SELECT item_master_id, sum(received_quantity), sum(ordered_quantity) FROM material_line_item
GROUP BY item_master_id
```

Comment: aliasing the sums would be wise as it makes it easier to reference.

Comment: By the way thanks @Matthew its working as per my requirement.

Comment: No problem :) glad to help

Comment: Hey @Matthew if I want to join another table with this query then how could I achieve this, and both the tables are having foreign key relation

Comment: Hey, so you would want to add a join:
LEFT JOIN next_table t ON t.next_ID = item_master_id.ID

Put this line before the GROUP BY statement

Comment: Afterwards you will have to add t.column_names to your select statement. Some of which may require further GROUP BY arguments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118446/discussion-between-ranjan-satpathy-and-matthew).

Comment: Sorry, my work blocks chat pages - I suppose post another SO question and someone will help you - sorry for spamming the comments

Answer (score 1):

Same as above solution but formatted :)

> `SELECT item_master_id
>       ,Sum(received_quantity) Total_Received_Qty
>       ,Sum(ordered_quantity) Total_Ordered_Qty
>   FROM material_line_item
>   GROUP BY item_master_id`